# facebook connect for android

Tags: android, facebook

I am looking for a solution for facebook connect for Android.

Before I used an open source solution from codecarpet:  http://code.google.com/p/fbconnect-android/

but now it doesnt work anymore.

Now the Official facebook connect for Android is out, but there are about 11 big time issues and it fails almost all the time, so its not a real solution. 
http://github.com/facebook/facebook-android-sdk/

Any idea how to resolve this issue?

Thanks

Comment: IIRC, facebook has their own API.  Implement that yourself.

Comment: Hi Daniel,  i have tested the FB sdk and it fails alll the time! =( where did you find the 11 big time issues, where i can find a documentation about this???, for my experience I had to make my own implementation based on fbconnect class files.

Comment: Hi Jorgesys,  here is the list of issues reported by the community back to the project.  http://github.com/facebook/facebook-android-sdk/issues  .   Did you base your implementation on the new implementation or old implementation? thanks

Comment: thanks for the info!, I get the class files from the .jar file, then i modify and fix some issues :) http://code.google.com/p/fbconnect-android/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

update.

Now Facebook connect for android works great.

http://github.com/facebook/facebook-android-sdk/

This is the best solution now.
Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a Facebook app
2. Embed a WebView in mobile, redirect to facebook mobile gateway
3. catch the redirect that runs beetween Facebook and your Facebook app server for post authorize
4. redirect from your server back to Facebook to get the permissions
5. once Facebook notifies your server that permissions are granted
6. request a sessions exchange from Facebook and it will return the session it to your server url

based on redirects that are placed in the webview you can detect if the user is logged in, and the session exchange is needed to as Facebook will place the session ID in your URL so you will be able to save it by processing  `getPath()`