# Facebook for Android application integration

Tags: android, facebook

Good day to all,

Can some one guide me in displaying a simple post from facebook application in `webview` in android application. When i post a message in FB, i need to show that message in my new feeds in emulator for android. I am able to post the message, But i need to display the posted message in the emulator screen. How can i do that. I have done with the facebook login screen, Authentication code. I am struck with displaying new feeds in native FB manner.

Any working example will be fine please send me the link.

Comment: Please check this post: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12889271/513413

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a very good tutorial, and should answer your questions on this subject.

[Facebook Integration](http://www.integratingstuff.com/2010/10/14/integrating-facebook-into-an-android-application/)

EDIT:

Here is an excellent facebook API. I use it for many projects. Works incredibly well!

[Easy Facebook](http://www.easyfacebookandroidsdk.com/guide.asp)

Comment: I have already registered with android and i have my app id. when i download the andriod sdk for facebook, I don find the layout(xml) code in facebook folder(Git). Secondly i am unable to add project references in file -> properties-> Add , I don get my source application. Where am i doing wrong. I know i have missed something, But not sure what is that. Please guide me.

Comment: i don understand how to work with the downloaded files. Do i need to copy the facebook folder to my application. Will that serve as a library file.

Comment: It should serve as a library. There is a beginners tutorial on the website above with Easy Facebook API. Works very well. Or download some of the examples they give.

Comment: Thanks a ton friend. Let me go thru the code and shall tell u if i have any doubt.