# Share Image and Text in Facebook,Twitter from Android Application

Tags: android, facebook, image, share, twitter4j

I am working in one Application where i can share my gallery image to facebook,twitter

i have searched the some links..Where everybody mentioned as intent service..but i do not know how it will use in my application,i would really be thankful if somebody help me with complete code

```
            Intent share = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            share.setType("image/jpeg");

            share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM,
              Uri.parse("file:///sdcard/DCIM/Camera/myPic.jpg"));

            startActivity(Intent.createChooser(share, "Share Image"));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this code:

```
    Button button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.facebookButton);

    button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    String path = "path to the image";
                    Uri imageUri = Uri.parse(path);

                    Intent sharingIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                    sharingIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                    sharingIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, imageUri);
                    sharingIntent.setType("image/png");

                     startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sharingIntent , "Send image using.."));

        }
    });
```

Comment: Is this automatically share the image

Comment: It's opening new intent but you need user interaction to continue the Share.

Comment: could you explain it better

Comment: on click share button i can share images using the above coding

Comment: What are you asking exactly? How to use the code that I posted? What are you missing there?

Comment: yes i need to know the full code ,,on click facebook button the image is sharing ,

Comment: is this same for facebook and twitter

Comment: Yes it's the same. You only need to have installed facebook and Twitter apps on your device, and when the intent will pop up you will have all of the listed apps that are able to share that data.

Comment: you mean i need to integrate facebook ,twitter code ..with my apps

Comment: one more doubt is it necessary to integrate facebook twitter with my code

Comment: It's not, the intent will run facebook and twitter bu default. And accept and upvote the answer if that helped you :)

Comment: What kind of error are you getting? Can you post the stacktrace?

Comment: Your app is independent from facebook now.. The intnet is only passing the data true the Android OS and Android OS is telling the Facebook and Twitter apps to share the content. Is your app crashing or the facebook?

Comment: k..its fine,.can we see data in facebook..that the image is from that particular application

Comment: You gonna need a facebook integration for that.. That is a very complex problem.. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3372020/facebook-integration-in-android-application